# Using Spring's "jdbc:initialize-database", how do I run a script with a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, spring, stored-procedures, junit, initialization

I'm using Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE, JUnit 4.8.1, and MySQL 5.5.  I want to truncate all my table data before each test, but am getting errors in Spring even though I can execute the following script (truncate_tables.sql) fine via the command line …

```
drop procedure if exists truncate_tables;

delimiter #
create procedure truncate_tables()
begin
 declare tab_name varchar(64);
 declare done tinyint unsigned default 0;

 declare table_cur cursor for select t.table_name
 from
  information_schema.schemata s
  inner join information_schema.tables t on s.schema_name = t.table_schema
 where
   s.schema_name = database() and t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE';

 declare continue handler for not found set done = 1;

 open table_cur;
 repeat
   fetch table_cur into tab_name;
   set @cmd = concat('truncate table ', tab_name);

   prepare stmt from @cmd;
   execute stmt;
 until done end repeat;

 close table_cur;
end #

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
CALL truncate_tables;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

However, using this Spring application context …

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db" />
    <property name="username" value="myuser" />
    <property name="password" value="bypass" />
</bean>
...
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:truncate_tables.sql"/>
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:db-test-data.sql"/>    
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

However, I get the error

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near &apos;delimiter # create procedure truncate_tables() begin  declare tab_name varchar(6&apos; at line 1
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor419.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2618)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2568)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:842)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:681)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.executeSqlScript(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:184)

    ... 50 more
```

Any way I can fix the above script?  It is not an option to use the "extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests" extension in my JUnit tests.

Answer (score 7):

`<jdbc:script />` doesn't allow usage of DELIMITER statement in the included script but you can use the `separator` property with same result.

In your `truncate_tables.sql` use only the `#` delimiter and specify it in the `separator` property like so:

```
drop procedure if exists truncate_tables#

create procedure truncate_tables()
begin
 declare tab_name varchar(64);
 declare done tinyint unsigned default 0;

 declare table_cur cursor for select t.table_name
 from
  information_schema.schemata s
  inner join information_schema.tables t on s.schema_name = t.table_schema
 where
   s.schema_name = database() and t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE';

 declare continue handler for not found set done = 1;

 open table_cur;
 repeat
   fetch table_cur into tab_name;
   set @cmd = concat('truncate table ', tab_name);

   prepare stmt from @cmd;
   execute stmt;
 until done end repeat;

 close table_cur;
end #

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0#
CALL truncate_tables#
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1#
```

and in the application context...

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script separator="#" location="classpath:truncate_tables.sql"/>
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:db-test-data.sql"/>    
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't work because semicolon is used as statement separator.
You can define `ResourceDatabasePopulator` and `DataSourceInitializer` beans with custom separator:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/ResourceDatabasePopulator.html#setSeparator(java.lang.String) .

See (unresolved)
https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8817.